# java.net.socketException:operation time out when running app on real device

Tags: android, connection, out, socketexception

this code works fine on emulator, but on real device it gives

> *java.net.SocketException*:the operation timed out
>   ive got a php script running on my xampp server.

```
package com.example.new1;


 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;

 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  TextView tx;
  StringBuilder stringBuilder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tx= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
}

public void func(View view)
{
    //tx.setText("Working fine till here.");
     new FetchSQL().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
private class FetchSQL  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>

{   

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            URL url = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String myUrl = "http://10.22.35.4:80/conc2.php";
        try
        { url =new URL(myUrl);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          connection.setReadTimeout(15*10000);
          connection.connect();
          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
          stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

          }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch(final Exception e)
        {
             return e.toString();
          }

    } 

    protected void onPostExecute(final String result)
    {
        tx.setText(result);
    }


}
```

}

when i click on button it takes the amt of time ive set in my code, and then fails giving me the error in my textview. please help

my php code.

```
<?php
// attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=10.22.35.11 dbname=iwmp_dev2 user=postgres "); 

 if (!$dbh) {
 die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
 }       

 // execute query
 //$sql = $_POST['pLat'];
 $sql = "SELECT officer_name FROM iwmp_officer";

 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
 die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }       
 $array = array();
// iterate over result set
// print each row
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result, null)) {
  $i++;
  $array = implode('+',$row);
 echo $array; 

 }


    // free memory
    pg_free_result($result);       

     // close connection
     pg_close($dbh);
       ?>
```

Comment: Where did you put your php file?

Comment: set a http connection time out for your http connection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075506/http-connection-timeout-on-android-not-working

Comment: Please, refer to this post, it may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/8240338/1292544

Comment: try making a connection to the url using browser on the real device

Comment: @nitish ive put the php file in xampp htdocs folder

Comment: when debuging.. using my device.. i m getting.._java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable_ at  connection.connect();

Comment: Well you had passed url of localhost. Try to pass your machine's ip address. Refer to the link, that I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: the link u gave is giving problem .. for that _envelop_ thing..  n i already tried it with machine ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.net.SocketException exception comes when the port that you are trying to reach is not closed or not available. It takes the amount of time you have specified for searching the port and then gets out.

Firstly, try to call this service on your mobile web browser to check whether it is available or not. If it does not show that means your device is not connected to the network on which this file resides.

It may be possible that your firewall is not allowing to ping your port. When you are doing with your emulator it works since its on same PC but in case of your real device it connects via local network and some time Firewall does not allow. Solution: unblock this request on firewall or try this by closing your firewall.